# How to quick enter the math mode delimiters ($ $) using WinEdt?

Tags: math-mode, winedt

Just like `$6/8f=2/8f + 4/8f$`. Forgive my laziness, and I don't want to repeatedly enter the `$$`. So, is there any shortcut key or something that can help me type the `$$` immediately, or select the letter and just a click to change `AAA` to `$AAA$`.

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: @LeoLiu WinEdt is the name of the editor (see tag and title).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no predefined shortcut for this in WinEdt.

Anyway you can add one, for instance <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> which is not used anywhere else.

To do this (assuming you have version 7 or greater), go to "Options" -> "Options Interface" and, in the branch "Menus and Toolbar", double-click on "Main Menu". A local copy of the file `MainMenu.ini` will be opened.

At this point, locate the item

```
ITEM="$...$"
  CAPTION="$...$"
  IMAGE="Omega"
  MACRO="IfSel(2,'>',!'SetSel(0);');InsLabel('','$','$');"
  REQ_DOCUMENT=1
```

and add the line

```
  SHORTCUT="16458::Ctrl+J"
```

so to have

```
ITEM="$...$"
  CAPTION="$...$"
  IMAGE="Omega"
  MACRO="IfSel(2,'>',!'SetSel(0);');InsLabel('','$','$');"
  SHORTCUT="16458::Ctrl+J"
  REQ_DOCUMENT=1
```

Now press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to incorporate the changes and you're done.

As you can see in the "Insert" -> "LaTeX" menu, now the item "$..$" has the proper shortcut.

[image]

---

If you also want a button in the toolbar that is associated with that command, do the following.

In the same branch of the "Option Interface", double-click on "Toolbar". A local copy of the file `Toolbar.ini` will be opened.

Now locate the line

```
BUTTON="Emphasize_(Italic)"
```

and just before it, insert the line

```
BUTTON="$...$"
```

As before, press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to incorporate the changes.

And here is your toolbar button:

[image]

Comment: It works, and I have the question. It is obvious that winedt  has the function to auto fill the `$$`. So besides the shortkey, is there any button to have the same function. Thanks very much

Comment: Of course, it works. And I change the word. :)

Comment: @ytyyutianyun See the image I've added in the answer.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun If you want a button in the toolbar, as well, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the following macro, heavily inspired by the fonts macros:

```
BeginGroup;  
IfSel('0','=',>  
  'SelWord(1);>  
   IfSel(''0'',''='',>  
         ''Ins("$  $");>  
           PreviousBullet;'',>  
         ''InsLabel(""," $ "," $ ")'');',>    
  'InsLabel(""," $ "," $ ");');  
EndGroup;  
End;
```

that is to be stored in `%b\Local\macros\`, say, as `insmath.edt`. Then you add an item to the SHORTCUTS menu in MainMenu.ini, and locate  the line: 
`END="Shortcuts"`. Add just above this line the item:

```
ITEM="InsertSel $ $"
  MACRO="Exe('%b\Local\macros\insmath.edt')"
  SHORTCUT="16570::Ctrl+$"
  REQ_DOCUMENT=1
```

Its job is to insert a $ $ pair on either side of a selection, selecting first the closest word if no selection is done.

You can also add two lines just above the 
`END="SelectedPopup"` line in PopupMenus.ini:

```
ITEM="Insert $  $"
  MACRO="[InsLabel('','$ ',' $')]"
```

You'll have access to this menu item with a right click on a selected text.

If you just want to typeset  `$ $` and get the cursor amidst, with only one key, you can make $ an active string adding these lines at the end of ActiveStrings.ini:

```
STRING="$"  
  START_FILTER="~\"  
  AFTER=0  
  ENABLED=1  
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"  
  MACRO="[SelCharLeft;Ins(' $  $');PreviousBullet;]"
```

Now `$` is a shortcut, provided that you're in TeX mode and you did not type `\$`. As far as I can see it, there is no other situation in which one might type `$`for something else than entering in-line math mode.

Of course you'll have to incorporate the changes to each of the modified .ini files (Load Current Script in the Options Interface).

Comment: Sorry, there a problem typesetting the last line of code: the content of Ins is supposed to be " $ bullet $", the bullet being  obtained in WinEdt with "Alt+Ctrl+Space".

Comment: Thank you, @bernard, but excuse me, there is no `END="SelectedPopup"` in PopupMenus.ini:

I can only find `MENU="SelectedPopup"` and `SELECTED_POPUP="SelectedPopup"`

Comment: Which version of WinEdt do you have? There was a change on passing from version 7 to version 8: all MENU="some menu" now end with END="some menu" in MaiMenu.ini and PopupMenus.ini. I suppose this is to prevent any ambiguity as to where a menu ends and the following one begins.

Comment: Thank you, then I save the insmath.edt in `C:\CTEX\WinEdt\Local\Macros`, edit `MainMenu.ini` and `PopupMenus.ini`. But when I right click the mouse, no extra item appears. why?  And the second command is to type `Ctrl+$`, how can I type this in the keyboard

Comment: There are a couple of errors. 1- Instead of `CMD("Previous Bullet");` it must be `CharLeft(2);`. 2- In an English keyboard the right shortcut is not `SHORTCUT="16570::Ctrl+$"` but `SHORTCUT="16570::Ctrl+;"`. 3- The macro for the active string must be `MACRO="[SelCharLeft;Ins(' $  $');CharLeft(2);]"` and not `MACRO="[SelCharLeft;Ins(' $  $');PreviousBullet;]"`.

Comment: Is `PreviousBullet` deprecated ? I used it on purpose: I prefer to have a spacebetween each $ and the math contents (matter of better legibility, in my opinion); and I prefer not to keep all spaces in document settings, in order to prevent unwanted indefinite expansion of spaces. A bullet allowed me to obtain this result.

Comment: As to the shortcut problem, it's not easy to know what memonic will be available on other keyboards — I would have said that something like Ctrl+Shift+4 would have been OK on english keyboards, as $ is on the 4 key, but maybe that's a naive point of view…

Comment: Sorry, Bernard, I didn't see the bullets in the code. You can paste them here from WinEdt. Anyway `CMD("Previous Bullet");` is deprecated, use `PreviousBullet;` instead. :-)

Comment: Oops! I had modified one macro, not both… Of course I know CMD is deprecated. I modified my answer consequently.

Comment: As to the bullet, I tried to copy it from WinEdt, but nothing is visble. A site's problem, maybe?

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: if nothing appears when you right-click on a selection, I suspect you didn't incorporate the change in Popup.ini, but only saved Popup.ini. In order to incorporate the change you can either type Shift Ctrl  F9 while PopupMenus.ini is frontmost in WinEdt, or click on Load Current Script button in the Option Interface (leftmost button).

Comment: Yes,it works, but when type `Ctrl+$` ,nothing happens,but type `Ctrl+;` is right as @karlkoeller says. But the code is `ITEM="InsertSel $ $"
  MACRO="Exe('%b\Local\macros\insmath.edt')"
  SHORTCUT="16570::Ctrl+$"
  REQ_DOCUMENT=1  `  So in the keyboard, `$` is not the `shift+4` but `;`. right? Thank you

Comment: Yes, one has to adapt the shortcut to one's own keyboard.